# what is the return value of system command when used in c

Tags: c, shell

I am using linux system command to kill some processes in c file. I just want to know the different return values that are possible. I dont get clear idea when i searched the net. the following command i am using in c.

```
ret = system("pkill raj");
```

- suppose that if there are no processes running with raj what will be the return value?
- suppose that if the command pkill raj is failed what will be the return value?
- suppose there are some process that are with name raj. after executing this what will be the return value.

Comment: Are you aware of the manual pages? Like the ones you get when typing `man -s3 system` in a Linux/UNIX terminal?

Comment: hmm yeah.. went trhough it .. it was bit difficult to interpret whats mentioned over there.. :(

Comment: You should learn to read and understand the man pages. It's an essential skill while developing on UNIX and one without which you'll be quite crippled.

Answer (score 3):

from the man page:

> The value returned is -1 on error (e.g.  fork(2) failed), and the
>   return status of the command otherwise.  This latter return
>          status  is  in  the  format  specified  in wait(2).  Thus, the exit code of the command will be WEXITSTATUS(status).  In case
>          /bin/sh could not be executed, the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127).

So you need to check WEXITSTATUS(ret) for the return value of your pkill command.

code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int status;
        if(( status = system("kill -9 13043")) != -1){
                fprintf(stdout, "kill command exit status: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: WEXITSTATUS is only valid if the command exited (WIFEXITED( status ) is nonzero ).  Consider system( "kill $$" ).  See wait(2).

Answer (score 0):

System will return the exit status of pkill  unless the call to system fails.  pkill returns these somewhat ridiculous values,

```
 EXIT STATUS
  0      One or more processes matched the criteria.
  1      No processes matched.
  2      Syntax error in the command line.
  3      Fatal error: out of memory etc.
```

which preclude their use to kill processes by pattern if the current running state of the process is unknown.  For example, if you run 'pkill raj' and get a return value of 1, it is because pkill failed to match 'raj' not because it failed to kill the raj process, which will result in a return value of 0 with an error message on stderr.  I would recommend against the use of pkill for this reason.  Use pgrep to match process names, and once you have a pid, use kill to kill that pid.